# How can I check what ports an app is using so I can enable them in ufw?

Tags: networking, ufw

With the soon to be demise of Ubuntu One I started looking at other ways to store backup in the cloud. I already had the Dropbox client installed and have been storing back ups there for now.

Not wanting to use all of my space there this got me to looking at ways to manage my other personal clouds with Google, OneDrive and Box. After some research I came across a solution [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-to-access-and-use-cloud-storage-skydrive-etc-in-linux/) using [this software](http://storagemadeeasy.com/LinuxDrive/) . It isn't as good of a solution as a native client, but it does work.

The problem I am running into is with UFW enabled the client cannot connect. I have looked through SMES' paltry FAQ and scoured the internet until my eyes bleed to no avail.

Is there any way to find out what ports need to be opened in UFW for this to work without shutting UFW off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking what ports are open on your computer. You can tell this with the `nmap` and `ifconfig` commands.

Install nmap with:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Run `ifconfig` and find the network interface your using (ethernet usually uses `eth0` and wifi uses `wlan0`). Look for the `inet` address. This is your local address.

Now scan your computer for open ports with nmap:

```
sudo nmap -p 1-65535 <address>
```

Where `<address>` is the `inet` address you found earlier. This will scan your computer and tell you what daemons/services are listening on what ports. Your program should be there.

You'll need to allow this port through ufw with:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port <port>
```

Or just:

```
sudo ufw allow <port>/tcp
```

Where `<port>` is the port we just found.

Comment: @ Seth ran as you advised and this was the output `sudo nmap -p 1-65535 192.168.1.8

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-04-07 22:38 CDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.8
Host is up (0.000022s latency).
Not shown: 65534 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
17500/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.66 seconds
brian@Presario:~$`   Screenshot @ http://imageshack.com/a/img716/6016/r5eg.png

Comment: Well you've got one port open.  Try allowing that one: `sudo ufw allow 17500/tcp`.  Make sure you remember to turn the firewall back on!

Comment: Seems to have fixed it at this point although during the course of all this I have found another issue with the app signing in using https vs http. (Another question in and of its own) :/ Looks like they are using the Dropbox LAN sync protocol.